# How to get the margins of a View, moved to a position which isn't known at run time

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, margins, layoutparams

As of right now I'm working on an Android App which provides some tools trainers can use to communicate with their trainees, one of the tools is a lineup editor which consists out of drag and drop able spinners*.

*there is a default Layout set->football Lineup: 4/4/2

If the User presses the saveBtn, the lineup gets saved as Custom obj. called lineup which holds 2 Arrays with x and y coords. It gets repsesented in a Recyclerview which holds a button called "Edit". By pressing on the edit button i want to show the saved lineup by setting those x and y coords to the spinners in the default edit-mode activity.

My problem with all this is, that the programm always returns the default margins set in the .xml.

I tried it with .getLeft and .getBottom which you can see here:

```
public Lineup saveLineup(){
    int[] x=new int[10];
    int[] y=new int[10];
    LayoutParams[] layouts=new LayoutParams[10];

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        x[i]=positions[i].getLeft();//positions contains all the spinners used in the .xml
        y[i]=positions[i].getBottom();
    }
    Lineup lineup=new Lineup(x,y);
    return lineup;
}
```

To drag and drop i am overwriting the OnTouch Methode as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                view.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getLeft()`, `getBottom()` methods, use `getLocationOnScreen(int[] outLocation)` to get coordinates of the view relative to the screen.

```
int[] outLocation = new int[2];
position[i].getLocationOnScreen(outLocation);

int marginleft=outLocation[0];
int margintop=outLocation[1];
```

See this for details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])